# Iterate through child to parent

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm claming data from following query,

```
    var targetItems = await _dbContext.TargetItems
        .Include(ti => ti.BranchTargetItem)
        .ThenInclude(bti => bti.BranchTarget)
        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

I need to find a way to sum values from bottom to top level in my tree. Must sum values respectively regarding its own first level child values like I commented out below,

```
targetItems = {
   "item":"A",
   "values":14, << sum of B + C values
   "childs":[
      {
         "item":"B",
         "values":2,
         "childs":[]
      },
      {
         "item":"C", << sum of D + E + H values
         "values":12,
         "childs":[
            {
               "item":"D",
               "values":5,
               "childs":[]
            },
            {
               "item":"E",
               "values":4, << sum of F + G values
               "childs":[
                  {
                     "item":"F",
                     "values":2,
                     "childs":[]
                  },
                  {
                     "item":"G",
                     "values":2,
                     "childs":[]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "item":"H",
               "values":3,
               "childs":[]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Not able to post any code here because, I am not even close to solution.

Comment: Can you at least post the class that holds these items, or is it a json that you need to parse/deserialize?

Comment: @ZoharPeled My classes are very close to example json, I just simplified the example output for being understandable.

Comment: Is each node of the same type? If so you could recurse.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Yes each node is exactly same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int SetSumOfChildren(object node){
  if(!(node.childs?.Any() ?? false)){
    node.values = node.values ?? 0;
  }
  else {      
    int sum = 0;
    foreach(var n in node.childs){
      sum += SetSumOfChildren(n);
    }
    node.values = sum;
  }
  return node.values;
}

SetSumOfChildren(data);
```

Comment: It worked as expected, thank you so much. Recursive method is really good practice.